# In Microsoft Word, how to disable typeface shortcut keys from changing typeface when nothing is selected?

Tags: microsoft-word

I apologize for the confusing title. Here is an explanation of the behavior I would like to customize.

In Microsoft Word, the "typeface" shortcut keys (<kbd>Ctrl+I</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl+B</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl+U</kbd>) serve two roles:

1. to change the typeface of text already typed; and
2. to change the typeface that will be used for the text about to be typed.

Role (1), in turn, will occur in two different contexts:

- (a) when text is selected; and
- (b) when the cursor is positioned in the middle of a word.

It is context (b) that is giving me difficulty, because it interferes with "track changes" (the full explanation is complicated, but, basically, Word treats a cursor as "in the middle of a word" even if half the word is "inserted" and the other half is "deleted"--arguably a bug).

I would therefore like to disable (b). Specifically, **I would like to make it so that when <kbd>Ctrl+I</kbd> is pressed and no text is selected, no typeface is changed.**

Is this possible?

Comment: Please advise which version of Word is in use. In any Word document, please do File | Account | About   and the year and release number are on the second line under About Microsoft Word. Once obtained, please click on `edit` above and to the left and add that to the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, with the following three VBA subroutines added to your Normal template, or added to a separate custom template that is loaded into Word's Startup folder, or in the document itself if it was a macro enabled ".docm" document.

```
Sub Bold()
'
' Bold Macro
' Makes the selection bold (toggle)
'
    If Not Selection.Range.Start = Selection.Range.End Then
        Selection.Font.Bold = wdToggle
    End If

End Sub
Sub Italic()
'
' Italic Macro
' Makes the selection italic (toggle)
'
    If Not Selection.Range.Start = Selection.Range.End Then
        Selection.Font.Italic = wdToggle
    End If

End Sub
Sub Underline()
'
' Underline Macro
' Formats the selection with a continuous underline (toggle)
'
    If Not Selection.Range.Start = Selection.Range.End Then
        If Selection.Font.Underline = wdUnderlineNone Then
            Selection.Font.Underline = wdUnderlineSingle
        Else
            Selection.Font.Underline = wdUnderlineNone
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```